# How to read XML file from solution location and bind the xml file with dll?

Tags: c#

I am creating a class library, and i have created a folder called config in the solution directory. and i placed one xml in the folder.

How to load the xml file in my class functions?

I tried like below, its not loading

```
        XmlDocument contentxml = new XmlDocument();
        String configxmlfile = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "Config\\instruction.xml";
        contentxml.Load(configxmlfile);
```

And I want to bind the xml file with the dll, becuase i am going to upload the dll in another application and i will call my classes from the dll, and my class will look for the xml file information there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to Embed a xml to the assembly

```
1. Right click the xml file and Select properties
2. In the Properties Pane Set the BuildAction as Embeded resource
So this Xml becomes a embeded resource when the application is compiled
```

Then you can read the xml from the assembly by the following code

```
   System.Reflection.Assembly _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
   System.IO.Stream _xmlStream = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("[[YourNamespace]].[[XMLFileName.xml]]");
   System.IO.StreamReader _textStreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(_xmlStream);
   string xml = _textStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can add a "Resource File" to your project and add the xml to this resource file(Resources.resx).

Here is some code for getting the content of the xml(config.xml in my example):

```
public class Class1
{
    public XDocument GetXml()
    {
        return XDocument.Parse(Resources.config);
    }
}
```

Now, in another project:

```
MyClassLibrary.Class1 c = new MyClassLibrary.Class1();
var xml = c.GetXml();
```